# zsh alias to remove all docker containers returns command not found

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I have this alias in my `.zshrc` file:

```
alias rmcons="docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)"
```

But after trying to execute it, it removes only one container and then it prints

```
$rmcons
ef8197f147fb
zsh: command not found: c2ea2673f9e4
zsh: command not found: 4603059f1618
zsh: command not found: 40ad60328595
```

How can I remove all containers that `docker ps -aq` shows?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to use single quotes (`''`) instead of double quotes (`""`).

```
alias rmcons='docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)'
```

---

If you use double quotes, than the *command substitution* `$(docker ps -aq)` will be evaluated when you define the alias. In your example this was equivalent to

```
alias rmcons="docker rm -f ef8197f147fb
c2ea2673f9e4
4603059f1618
40ad60328595"
```

As the newlines are command separators (like `;`) this alias is substituted by  four commands: `docker rm -f ef8197f147fb`, `c2ea2673f9e4`, `4603059f1618` and `40ad60328595`. The last three of which do not exist on your system, hence "command not found". It also means that the same output of `docker ps -aq` - as it was on alias definiton - will be used and not as it would be when running the alias.

On the other hand, if you use single quotes, the alias will actually substituted by the exact command you defined: `docker rm -f $(docker ps -aq)`. Although `docker ps -aq` will still return output with newlines, these newlines are now only parsed word separators between arguments.

Comment: Thanks! Just ran it, and it worked perfectly, didn't know about such difference

Comment: Why does the shortcut `alias dodownall='docker kill $(docker ps -q)'` still returns `"docker kill" requires at least 1 argument.`? 
The same when I try your command above.

Comment: @nonNumericalFloat That should only happen if the output of `docker ps -q` is empty (or contains only whitespace characters). The most likely cause for that would be that no containers are running (which might for example be caused by a prior run of `dodownall`). Does running `docker ps -q`  show anything for you in the cases where `dodownall` fails with the missing argument error?

Comment: Oh damn, nevermind. Silly me forgot to open a new bash...
Thank you!
I allowed myself to do a little edit ;D

Answer (score -1):

> Warning: untested. I  don't use/have docker.

I think you should serialize the output first "escaping" the new lines.

---

You might also use the `for` loop, trying:

```
for id in `docker ps -aq`; do docker rm -f $id; done
```

Note the backquotes to parse the command's output.

You can also directly use `$()` instead of its shortcut backquote.

I recommend to test with `echo` first instead of removing with `rm`:

```
for id in `docker -ps -aq`; do echo rm -f $id; done
```

, and to use the `rm` with its `-i` switch to prompt for confirmation before deleting.

I hope `docker`'s `rm` subcommand has one.